# Order of dimensions in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Is the first dimension always the Y-dimension (vertical one) while the second dimension refers to the X-dimension (horizontal one)? Is there any exceptions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no exceptions.

The only subtlety is that if you only specify 1 index (eg `x(10)`), that refers to the 10th element overall, not the 10th element in dimension 1.  So you have a `size(x)=[2 10]`, then `x(10) == x(2,5)`.

Comment: 10th element overall, _column-major_.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you need to keep in mind:

- MATLAB operates always along the first non-singleton dimension
- In a matrix, the first dimension is along rows and the second is along columns

Within this principles falls array indexing.

Another example, if you have a vector (abusing notation):

```
sum(reshape(1:3,[1,1,3])) == sum(1:3) == sum((1:3)')
```

if you have a matrix:

```
sum([1 2; 3 4]) ~= sum([1 2; 3 4],2)
```

i.e. sum along rows (also called column-wise) is different from the sum along columns (also called row-wise).